# How do robots see captcha? or a group of alpha-numeric characters?

Tags: captcha

like why do websites insist on entering captchas?
i think that even robots are capable of reading that...
I want to know how this thing with captcha work...:/

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

In the past 10 years robots were unable to identify distorted test as entered in captcha . But now a days robots can identify distorted text and even door number plates used in so many websites as captcha .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the perfect answer but you might want to take a look at [this blog post](http://blog.drwile.com/?p=10743) where author has mentioned that so far no program or robot has been able to read the CAPTCHA or any other form of distorted texts while computer programs can read the simple text or text in images, no such system has been so far developed to scan and read distorted texts or CAPTCHA.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thing called Turing Test which differentiates a machine an a Human. Captchas are formed so that machines fail that test. But using AI , now-a-days machines have started passing Turing tests.

Answer (score 0):

Captchas will typically display alphanumeric characters in a distorted way so that the human brain can process it in a way automatic character recognition can not. This trick is how the website administrator can tell humans and robots apart.

As machine learning algorithms get better, captchas are getting more complicated for actual humans to solve. This is an arms race between website administrators trying to keep their site safe from robots and hackers trying to create fake accounts in an automated way.

Google's reCAPTCHA asks you to read 2 fields. One is an actual captcha, the other is an image that Google's machine learning system has failed to read (such as a house street number from Google Street View). By solving this captcha, you are helping the machine to learn.